# how to remove previous marker automatically when new marker is added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, leaflet

[image]I have Zip codes drop down list and I want to display selected zip code on leaflet map. For that I did Geo coding to get lat long. Now I want when user selects another Zip code from drop down list, previous marker should removed automatically. Please suggest me.

```
$.ajax({
           url : "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=santa+cruz&components=postal_code:"+$scope.code+"&sensor=false",
           method: "POST",
           success:function(data){
               latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
               longitude= data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
               console.log('Your latitude is :'+latitude+' and longitude is '+longitude);
               var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);                    
                leafletData.getMap('lfdt').then(function(map){
                var marker= L.marker([latitude,longitude]).addTo(map);
                var group = new L.featureGroup([marker]);
                console.log("Group",group);
                map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
                map.setZoom(6);
                var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    if (results[1]) 
                    {
                    marker.bindPopup(results[1].formatted_address);
                        marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                            this.openPopup();
                        });
                        marker.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                            this.closePopup();
                        });
                    }
                    console.log("Location: " , results[1].formatted_address);
                }
                });                 
                console.log("geocode",geocoder);                                                                                                                
                });                                                                                             
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: this doesn't look like angularjs;  `$.ajax` is jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
var marker;
$.ajax({
       url : "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=santa+cruz&components=postal_code:"+$scope.code+"&sensor=false",
       method: "POST",
       success:function(data){

           latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
           longitude= data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
           console.log('Your latitude is :'+latitude+' and longitude is '+longitude);
           var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);                    
            leafletData.getMap('lfdt').then(function(map){

           if (marker) { // check
            map.removeLayer(marker); // remove
           }

            marker= L.marker([latitude,longitude]).addTo(map);
            var group = new L.featureGroup([marker]);
            console.log("Group",group);
            map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
            map.setZoom(6);
            var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                if (results[1]) 
                {
                marker.bindPopup(results[1].formatted_address);
                    marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                        this.openPopup();
                    });
                    marker.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                        this.closePopup();
                    });
                }
                console.log("Location: " , results[1].formatted_address);
            }
            });                 
            console.log("geocode",geocoder);                                                                                                                
            });                                                                                             
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i have tried this code but there is an error coming   .                    "TypeError: Cannot read property '_leaflet_id' of undefined". Please suggest me

Comment: I have updated the above code to handle undefined. Can you check now?

Comment: Still , I am getting previous markers when i updated code with this one.

Comment: please suggest me what should i do?

Comment: I checked your code and ran in my machine. Everything is looking good except address. You need to update address too along with postal code. If you do that, markers are pointing correctly. Check with address and let me know